# $W:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3\;|\;xy+3z=0,\text{ and }\;2x+y+z=0\}$ subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}.$ .

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble showing the first linear equation using the one-step vector subspace test, to prove that the set :
$W:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3\mid xy+3z=0\text{ and }2x+y+z=0\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}.$ .

Comment: Your first equation is a non-linear equation, so why do you think $W$ can be a subspace? Perhaps look for a counterexample.

Comment: Perhaps a typo and you mean $x+y+3z=0$ instead of $xy+3z=0?$

Answer (score 5):

$W$ is NOT a subspace because $(2,-12,8) \in W$ but $\frac{1}{2}(2,-12,8)=(1,-6,4) \not\in W$.

Answer (score 2):

It is NOT a subspace.  We can easily verify that $(-15,5,25)$ is an element of both surfaces:
$$(-15)(5)+3(25)=0$$
$$2(-15)+5+25=0$$

However if we scale this by two then $2\cdot(-15,5,25) = (-30,10,50)$ but this does NOT satisfy the first equation (which is NOT a plane):
$$-30\cdot 10 + 3\cdot 50=-150\neq0$$

Since $(-15,5,25)$ is an element of their intersection, it follows that if their intersection *were* a subspace then it would have to be closed under scaling (i.e. multiplying by a number)... however it is not.